# MD6 hash generation linux command for 128-bit, 256-bit, 512-bit MD6 hashes

Tags: linux, python, command, hashsum, checksum

there are multiple checksum commands in the GNU Core Utilities in most Linux distros for famous hashing algorithms like SHA2 or MD5, But I need a command for MD6 (message digest 6) checksum that can generate 128/256/512 bit size md6 hashes.

actually some programming languages has support for md6 in some of their libraries but I need a Linux command or at least a python library that supports md6 because most hash libraries don't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- GUI: https://github.com/tristanheaven/gtkhash
- Python: https://pypi.org/project/md6/#files
- PHP/JS: https://github.com/Snack-X/md6 | https://github.com/Neo-Desktop/md6 | https://github.com/Richienb/md6-hash
- Rust: https://docs.rs/md6/2.0.2/md6/
- Perl: https://github.com/AndyA/Digest--MD6
- Swift: https://github.com/ImKcat/CatCrypto

Comment: your answer contained libraries for a lot of languages that's why I am going to accept it for other people who view the question but the md6 python library you provided from pypi is a one I already tried and it just didn't work, it's a pre-release unfinished version and looks like it is no more developed because the last change to it was in 2009